# QPID C++ Broker and QPID-CPP SSL Certificates

Tags: c++, ssl, openssl, qpid, nss

I am trying to set up SSL with QPID and I'm having trouble figuring out how to set up the certificates. I have made a certificate database and added a self signed certificate to it like so:

```
mkdir ${CERT_DIR}
certutil -N -d ${CERT_DIR} -f ${CERT_PW_FILE}
certutil -S -d ${CERT_DIR} -n ${NICKNAME} -s "CN=${NICKNAME}" -t "CT,," -x -f ${CERT_PW_FILE} -z /usr/bin/certutil
```

I then started the QPID C++ Broker, passing it the `${CERT_DIR}`, the `${NICKNAME}` and the `${CERT_PW_FILE}`. The broker log tells me that the SSL listener is running on my port of choice.

However, I'm not sure what directory/certificate name I should give as environment variables when starting the QPID-CPP C++ client? I have tried passing the directory as `${CERT_DIR}` and the certificate name as `${NICKNAME}` but this doesn't seem to work; the QPID log prints the message:

```
**[System] error Error reading socket: SSL peer cannot verify your certificate [-12271].**
```

What is the correct procedure to set up a server and client certificate to use with QPID? It says it must be done using `certutil`.

Thanks

Comment: You want to do only server side TLS, right? No TLS client authentication. Did I got it right?

Comment: I want to test my code with both server side TLS only, as well as with TLS client authentication. I have moved to the QPID Proton C++ library now as it seems better supported, but that has not helped matters as there is no information in the documentation of QPID regarding using this client with SSL/TLS. I have successfully made the client work with the ActiveMQ broker, but I have had no luck with the QPID broker and its 'NSS database'.

Comment: And you want to use self-signed certificates on both sides? Or some sort of CA?

Comment: Just self signed for testing purposes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This works with QPID Proton 0.23.0 for the API and QPID CPP 1.38.0 for the C++ Broker.**

**Text included in** *italics* **is for those who desire client authentication.**

I figured out how to do it with self signed certificates:

1. Generate certificate database: `certutil -N -d [db-directory]`.
2. Generate CA certificate: `certutil -S -s "CN=[ca-name]" -n [ca-name] -x -t "CTu,CTu,CTu" -1 -2 -5 -k rsa -d [db-directory]`.
3. Generate server certificate: `certutil -S -s "CN=[server-cert-name]" -n [server-cert-name] -c "[ca-name]" -t "u,u,u" -m [unique-serial-no] -d [db-directory]`.
4. *Similarly, generate client certificate: `certutil -S -s "CN=[client-cert-name]" -n [client-cert-name] -c "[ca-name]" -t "u,u,u" -m [unique-serial-no] -d [db-directory]`.*

This generates the certificate database with the required certificates. Store the password used to create the certificate database in a file `[password-file]`. The QPID C++ Broker can then be started like so:

```
[path-to-qpidd] --ssl-cert-password-file [password-file] --ssl-cert-db [db-directory] --ssl-cert-name [server-cert-name]
```

*If you also require client authentication, pass the flag `--ssl-require-client-authentication`.*

In order to use the QPID Proton C++ client to connect via SSL, we must export our server certificate as a .pem file *and our client certificate as a cert.pem and a key.pem file*:

1. Export our server and client certificates as .p12 files: `pk12util -o [client/server].p12 -d [db-directory] -n [client-cert-name/server-cert-name]`.
2. Export the server certificate as a .pem file: `openssl pkcs12 -in server.p12 -out server.pem -nodes`.
3. *Export the client certificate as a certificate and a key .pem file:*

   - *Certificate: `openssl pkcs12 -in client.p12 -clcerts -nokeys -out clientcert.pem`.*
   - *Key: `openssl pkcs12 -in client.p12 -nocerts -out clientkey.pem`.*

These files can then be passed to the QPID Proton C++ API which will then be able to instantiate an SSL connection with the QPID broker.